# Slow loading the images from URL in UITAbleView.

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm loading the images from URL in UITableView. But it's very slow when loading an view. Here's an example,

```
UIImage *image = nil;
image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://calcuttans.com/palki/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/kidscover-small.png"]]];
```

In Table view, UIButton i'm setting the background image.

Please Can you provide the sample.

FYI : I'm used the LazzyTable sample program but it's not much helpful. Can you suggest any other samples.

Comment: use this [project](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), it will make the asynchronous loading for you

Comment: I think loading image in this way is synchronous call. Use sdwebimage as a uiimageview category hope it will help you.

Comment: I am amazed with the response. Thanks for all you answers. I will check it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Load image asynchronously

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://calcuttans.com/palki/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/kidscover-small.png"];
    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];


[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
        queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
        completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * response,
            NSData * data,
            NSError * error) {
    if (!error){
            NSImage* image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:data];
        // do whatever you want with image
    }

}];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works for me. And I would accept this as an answer.

Comment: sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use [NSURLSession dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:] (see NSURLSession.h)

Answer (score 3):

There are some open source libraries available for this:

1. [**HJCache**](https://github.com/markofjohnson/HJCache)
2. [**SDWebImage**](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

These libraries download image in a asynchronous manner and cache it for further use.

Comment: HJCache is far better than SDWebImage. easy to integrate and easy to understand with  fully functional.

Answer (score 2):

Try to implement [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking). It uses async requests to download the image, you are currently blocking your view with every download.

You can then use an [AFImageRequestOperation](http://afnetworking.github.com/AFNetworking/Classes/AFImageRequestOperation.html) to download your image.

Answer (score 2):

//Make use of dispatch queue for faster processing of data. add this in viewDidLoad

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    NSData * data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl]];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImage:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
});
```

//once data is got set the image and reload tableview

```
-(void)setImage:(NSData *)responseData
{
image = [UIImage imageWithData:responseData];
[tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you load the image all download from the internet every time , it must be very slow.

I think you shuold exist your download image to the filePath , and when you will load the image , you can check whether the image has been downloaded before , if not ,then download. if it has been downloaded , you can use `imageWithContentsOfFile:` method to load the image

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use [asihttprequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) to lazy load images. use ASINetworkQueues

Comment: Use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) instead of ASI as it is no longer being developed. (Even the author recommends not using ASI anymore.)

Answer (score 1):

You've to use `NSOperationQueue` to make your `tableview` efficient.

Check this [icodeblog tutorial](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/03/04/iphone-coding-turbo-charging-your-apps-with-nsoperation/) and [raywenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this tutorial. It helped me a lot. When I was using it I was quite new to iOS in general and it was helpful not only with respect to loading images from the web.

http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/

Answer (score 0):

With `AFNetworking` it is more easy.

//AFNetworking

```
#import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"

[cell.iboImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:server.imagen] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"qhacer_logo.png"]];
```