# IOS - long application launch as a result of XML parsing

Tags: ios, xml-parsing

my app is based on data, that I get from the web, in XML.
I implemented the NSXMLParser, and it works really good. the only (major) problem, is that
the launch of the app takes about 25 seconds!!! (the parser needs to parse 30 objects, each object has 5-7 elements- all are url's/strings).
so, it takes long time to start/end element, parse it, insert it to the right array, and so on...

Does parsing with Gdata or other api/object will take less time?

Comment: well, less means about 1/3 less :)

Comment: How many bytes? Parsing text is fast, it's most likely the downloading from the web that's slow.

Comment: if you mean the size of the xml file, its 4kb.

Comment: 25 seconds for that little data is a bit long.... RSS parsers don't take that much time. Are you sure that's really this stuff that's causing the problem ? Have you profiled your app ? Or is it because you need to download something from the parsed urls ?

Comment: the problem is there's an Images at every "object". after I disabled  parsing and fetching the images- the launch takes 6-8 seconds!!!!

Comment: It's still a lot anyway... Looks like there are several design problems in your app. There's a tut http://www.raywenderlich.com/30445/afnetworking-crash-course on afnetworking you might find helpfull. Also, if you can, use json instead of XML. Its declarative structure makes it a lot easier to handle. There's a very good stanford iPhone course on iTunes http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/ too.

Comment: @Alex, the guy who i'm writing the app for, has a website + an android app. both working with XML, so switching to json is not possible in that case...

Comment: Got it, but 6 sec is too long anyway. Nsxmlparser is fine to use, and probably not the reason why your app is slow to respond. There are design issues that you have to address and at this point it's probably better if you look into courses. The Stanford courses have an app about image downloading from Flickr. That may be a starting point for you. You may get valuable insights from that.

Comment: i'll check that right away :), many thanks!

Comment: solved with loading image asynchronously --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14579079/slow-loading-the-images-from-url-in-uitableview

Comment: @Alex, thanks for the response, i'll check the Stanford courses anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Downloading data from the Internet, on the main thread, when launching the app is VERY BAD. If a user has a slow (or no) connection, iOS will actually kill the app before it finishes because it is taking too long to respond.

You must launch your app very quickly and show the user the initial view without any delay.

In your case, show a mostly empty view indicating that it is accessing data. Then start the file download and processing in the background. When the data is processed, then update the main view on the main thread allowing the user to continue.

You should also consider supplying the app with some initial default data so you app is usable and useful even if the user can't connect to the Internet. This default data could also be whatever was downloaded the last time the app was used.

Comment: This is the way to go for you. Also consider to to add som progress bar (e.g. 0% to 100%) to the download/parsing. That way the user is obliged to way until it is finished, instead of just an activity indicator.

Comment: many thanks for the responses. I have NO idea how to do that, but I'll try to find something about it. if you guys have any link or something, I'll be very thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing on the background thread will make your app more responsive.

Comment: I thought about it but- the app needs the data to launch - there's no view to show without it. as far as I know, why to run a thread if nothing needs to happen at the same time. am i right?

Comment: Did you consider pre-loading app with some initial data? You can show that data (even if it is outdated) and fetch new data after you show some view to the user.