# Xcode, UIImage is NIL when i trying to implement Load image asynchronously

Tags: xcode, uiimage, nsurlconnection

I trying to implement Load image asynchronously.

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:_posterImg];
    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * response,
                                               NSData * data,
                                               NSError * error) {
                               if (!error){
                                   UIImage *getImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
                                   // do whatever you want with image
                               }

                           }];
```

But when i put this code, getImg will get warning "Unused Variable". i had check "response", "data" and "error", it all look fine but the getImg is NIL. is that i had write any thing wrong? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The affected variable is `response`. Although you use data and error, response is only declared as a parameter but nowhere used in your completion handler!

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:_posterImg];
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * response,
                                           NSData * data,
                                           NSError * error) {
                           NSString *errorMsg = nil;
                           UIImage *getImg = nil;
                           if (!error){
                               getImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
                           }
                           else 
                           {
                              errorMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Failed to load image. Error Message: %@", [error localizedString]];
                           }                              

                           [self handleImageRequestWithResponse:response image:getImg andErrorMessage:errorMsg];

                       }];
// Image hasn't load yet here since the request is asynchronously!
//if(getImg != nil && errorMsg == nil)
//    NSLog(@"Image is available!");
//else 
//    NSLog(@"Loading the image asynchronously failed! %@", errorMsg);


// In addition now provide the following method.
- (void) handleImageRequestWithResponse:(NSURLResponse*)response image:(UIImage*)img andErrorMessage:(NSString*)err
{
    if(img!= nil && err == nil)
        NSLog(@"Image is available!");
    else 
        NSLog(@"Loading the image asynchronously failed! %@", err);

    // Handle image
};
```

**EDIT:** My bad! Since the code executes asynchronously getImg was of course nil when you checked as before

---

**EDIT:**

Using `NSData dataWithContentsOfURL` is synchronous,i.e. if executed on the main thread your application is blocked.
See this official documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithContentsOfURL:

Most important:

> Important: Do not use this synchronous method to request network-based URLs. For network-based URLs, this method can block the current thread for tens of seconds on a slow network, resulting in a poor user experience, and in iOS, may cause your app to be terminated.

Going for a completionHandler and a handler method called after the requested raw data has been handled/prepared is better for your performance and does not violate the official recommendation!

Comment: sorry, i not understand your means. can you explain to me where why the getImg never get data? because i try to put NSLOG inside the (!error), it works fine to show the log.

Comment: Well you didn't ask for why the getImg is always nil.

Okay I'll wrap it up. You declare `UIImage *getImg` and assign the newly created image. 
This however is not "using (=read-access)" the variable, since you don't pass it somewhere, you don't access one of its properties or return it.

That is why getImg is displayed as a unused variable.
This does not mean that getImg and thus the image has not been initialized with the data loaded from the server!
To check whether you received data and the image is created properly you could use some checks like `if(data == nil)` or `if(getImg == nil)`.

Comment: sorry. i am lost. actually i am reference by <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14579079/slow-loading-the-images-from-url-in-uitableview> to implement. Previous before i implement the load image asynchronously, "UIImage *getImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];" is work fine. so now you means if i want use the completionHandler, i need use other way to assign the image on getImg?

Comment: So your problem is a "unused variable" warning. This is because you just assign to getImg but never use it somewhere else. The asynchronous approach is absolutely OK and should work. I'm pretty sure your image is available, however only within the completionHandler since this is the place where you declared the variable. 

COnsider my updated answer.

Comment: ya. thanks a lot for the "unused variable". but getImg is still get NIL. i am sure the "url" is valid data.

Comment: Please update your question with all the relevant example data ( Url etc. ) to evaluate it.
Also add a NSLog as i've updated my answer!

Comment: thanks a lot. i think i found out why it nil, just a misunderstand for when NSURL to NSData.

Comment: if that can give some guideline for "NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];" how to implement on the completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * response, NSData * data, NSError * error)? thanks a lot.

Comment: i still fail to show out the getImg. is that means i not need use "dataWithContentsOfURL" on completionHandler? Now the return is "Image is available", but the image not showing.